# Text in CSS Flip Animation won't align properly

Tags: css, animation

I'm currently trying to get a flip animation in css (I found on here) to work and fit my page. 
The animation works fine now, but the text, I want to include, won't align properly in the center of the front and back. I could add padding or make the font or text smaller, but is there another method to get everything centered atleast.

Resizing the larger portions of text on the back I could do separately when it's centered.

Check out the jsfiddle and you'll understand what I mean.

Examples: https://jsfiddle.net/glueckskind/kfhy7fh3/

```
  /* entire container, keeps perspective */
  .flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
  /* ADDED */
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
  /* flip the panel when hovered */
  .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  .flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 340px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;

  }

  /* flip speed goes here */
  .flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
  /* ADDED */
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* hide back of panel during swap */
  .front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  /* ADDED */
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 22px;

  }

  /* front panel, placed above back */
  .front {
    z-index: 2;
  /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /* ADDED */
  /* padding: 10px; makes one line ok */
    font-weight: 500;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
  }

  /* back, initially hidden panel */
  .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /* ADDED */
  /* padding: 10px; makes one line ok */
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
height: auto;
```

to .back

https://jsfiddle.net/kfhy7fh3/2/

Comment: Thanks. I knew that it would be simple.. well, I'm still a noob. :D

Comment: That's why you have us!

Comment: Do you have a solution, when i want to keep the panels the same size ?

Comment: Yea! :)
You could simply use flexbox.

Comment: Flexbox looks like an amazing tool ! Could center pretty easily, but now I wanted to see if I could make the text relative to it's size and found a lot of solutions, but none really helped or worked for my document. This looked like the best method - http://jsfiddle.net/MYSVL/2/ , BUT I tried it in mine and this happend - http://jsfiddle.net/glueckskind/mw6f3d4j/1/  ..Nothing.. :D

Comment: Du spricht doch bestimmt deutsch oder? :o
Ein kleiner Logikfehler bringt deinen gesamten Code durcheinander. 
$(".back p") selektiert nur das erste der drei Elemente, d.h. deine dritte backside wird mit diesem Befehl nicht selected. Entweder Du nutzt .each (jquery Function), siehe http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/, um jedes der Elemente auszuwählen und deiner Abfrage zu unterziehen oder Du nutzt meinen Code, welcher nur das letzte Element auswählt.
http://jsfiddle.net/mw6f3d4j/2/ (die Variante mit .last())
Vergess bitte bei JSFiddle nicht JQuery auszuwählen.

Comment: Aah. Wieder was gelernt. :D  Aber in deinem Code sind jetzt für mich alle hinteren Panels gleich groß, obwohl der .last() Befehl aufgeführt ist. Liegt das an meinem Browser oder lässt .last() dann alle Texte auf der Backside nach dem letzten/größten Text anpassen ?

Comment: Upsii :o
Natürlich musst du auch hier: $('.back p').css('font-size', (parseInt($('.back p').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px"); .last() anwenden.
http://jsfiddle.net/mw6f3d4j/3/

Comment: Irgendwie will es in meinem ganzen Code nicht funktionieren. Hast du, ohne den ganzen Code zu sehen, eine Idee, was ich vllt vergessen habe ? (Habe jQuery 3.1.1 vor meinem JavaScript im head gelinkt und die '.back p' sind in vielen verschiedenen anderen Divs eingebaut.)  Und wie würde man es machen, wenn man einige Panels mit langen Texten mit einer weiteren .class ausstattet, um diese dann mit dem .each Befehl alle auszuwählen ? ('.back .class' funktioniert nicht oder ?)

Comment: Gebe den Boxen in deinen Div's einfach eine ID und rufe die ID statt $(".back p") ab. Einfach $("#id").
In deinem HTML Code würde eine zweite Klasse so aussehen: <div class="klasse1 klasse"></div>. Einfach die Klassen der Div ohne Komma auflisten und dann mit $(".klasse") abrufen.

Comment: Wäre diese Lösung - $('.backtext').each(function() { .. }); - denn valide ? Funktionieren tut es bei mir schon mal :D

Comment: Sehe jetzt doch schon ein Problem. Jetzt werden wohl alle Texte an das erste .backtext Element angepasst. Wenn es nur drei Zeilen beträgt werden die weiteren Rückseiten nicht genug geschrumpft. Muss ich also für jeden zu langen Text eine ID + separate jQuery Funktion anlegen ?

Comment: Habe jetzt innerhalb der Funktion, $('.back p') mit $(this) ersetzt. Scheint zu funktionieren.

Comment: Hab eine komplett andere Frage. Leider kann man sich keine Nachrichten schicken, deshalb mache ich es nochmal hier, falls du nochmal Lust hast mir zu helfen. :D Ich möchte gerne ein Submenu in meinen fixed Header anbringen, wenn ich zu einem bestimmten Topic scrolle. Habe jetzt drei verschiedene Ideen von denen die eine ansatzweise gut funktioniert. Vielleicht kannst du ja mal drüber schauen.

Comment: Morgen schaue ich gerne drüber, hab in letzter Zeit viel zu tun :o Sorry :)

Comment: Wenn du Discord, Ts3 oder so hast, kann ich dir gerne auch darüber helfen :)

Comment: Sollst dir kein Bein ausreißen dafür. Wirklich nur wenn du Lust drauf hast. Ich hatte mal Discord..

Comment: Discord - glueckskind #8037

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers have default margin or padding, in this case as I see just reset margin element to 0.
This has happened to me in many times

```
`<pre>
.back p {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
</pre>
`
```